# UICollectionView Animations

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview, cabasicanimation

I have a `UITableview` and in each cell I have a horizontal `UICollectionView`. What I want to do is to show thumbnails for every image and when tapped. It's scaled and centered screen. A same animation is applied in an application called [Moma](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/moma/id383990455?mt=8). Can any one tell me how this animation is achieved. What I've done so far is by calling `UITablviewScrollPositionMiddle` and and that of `CollectionviewCenteredHorizontally` but I'm unable to achieve that. I know this will be done via `CABasicAnimation`. But don't know how to achieve that series of animation and scale/descale other rows. The video of this animation is [Here](http://sendvid.com/7lbvd7js).

Comment: The app in the video looks more like a hybrid JS app.

Comment: Did you done the cell to be middle?

Comment: Yup. It doesn't work because there is already an animation in progress.